# Python: Comparing values within a list

Tags: python

I have a list in my python program, I am wanting to compare each value in the list to every other value and if the values are equal to each other then print the iterative value in the list e.g ages[1]. Here is the codes so far

```
ages = [16, 16, 15]
for i in ages:
    for x in ages:
        if i == x:
            print(i, "=", x)
```

Currently this is giving me an output of

```
16 = 16
16 = 16
16 = 16
16 = 16
15 = 15
```

I understand that it is comparing each value in the list without the omission of the values already dealt with as well as that the print function is only giving the current value of the iteration. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: What output *are* you expecting?

Comment: An output of the "(the number of the iteration) = (the number of the other iteration)" E.g. ages[1] = ages[2]

Comment: The *index*, or the *value*? It's unclear why you expected the code you've shown to do anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not repeat any comparisons

```
ages = [16, 16, 15]
l = len(ages)
for i in range(l):
    for x in range(i+1,l): # range(i+1,l) makes sure that you don't compare with itself OR repeat any comparisons
        if ages[i] == ages[x]:
            #print(ages[i], "=", ages[x])
            print("ages[{}] = ages[{}]".format(i, x))
```

```
ages[0] = ages[1]
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue of repeated values, now would it be possible to have the output as the positions in the list, e.g. ages[0] = ages[1] instead of the actual variable?

Comment: Thank you, that has resolved my issue. One last question, this outputs the value of 0 = 1, and when I added     print("ages",i,"ages", x)       it has spaces between. Is it possible to print this without the spaces?

Comment: `print("ages%i ages%i" %(i,x))`

Comment: Thank you, that has clarified my issues.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to use `enumerate`:

```
ages = [16, 16, 15]
for i, x in enumerate(ages):
    for j, y in enumerate(ages[i+1:]):
        if x == y:
            print(f"{i}/{i + 1 + j}: {x}")
```